# Spring Jackson - Unrecognized field \"response\" not marked as ignorable at

Tags: java, json, jackson

i need to serialize a jSon String with jackson to an Object.

The string i get is

```
{"response":{"status":1,"count":"90120"}}
```

My object is

```
@JsonRootName("response")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Wrapper {

    private String count;

    private int status;

    private String registration_error;

    private int usable;

// getters and setters
```

So, this is how i'm trying to get my Wrapper

```
String response = {"response":{"status":1,"count":"90120"}};
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Wrapper w = mapper.readValue(response, Wrapper.class);
```

But when i log it i get

```
Wrapper [count=null, status=0, registration_error=null, usable=0]
```

What's wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to use `@JsonRootName`?

Comment: Yes, i tried `@JsonRootName` and `@JsonTypeName`... same error

Comment: Are you sure you're using `org.codehaus.jackson` annotations and not `com.fasterxml.jackson`?

Comment: yes... checked twice all my imports about jackson

Comment: Works fine for me. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, i set up things better and i don't get the exception anymore, but the Wrapper is all null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are usin @jsonRootName annotation which is correct. However, the annotation does not work on its own. You have to configure DeserializationFeature for object mapper. Your code should look like:

```
    String response="{\"response\":{\"status\":1,\"count\":\"90120\"}}";
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

 //mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true); This is for serailization time
            Wrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(response, Wrapper.class);
```

Check wrapper , It is having count and status as given in the json.

Comment: i'm getting this exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'response' does not match expected ('Wrapper') for type [simple type, class it.besmart.easyparking.web.client.wrapper.Wrapper]
 at [Source: {"response":{"status":1,"count":"90127"}}; line: 1, column: 2]`

Comment: Looks like you have either ommited @JsonRootName("response") on top of     Wrapper class or you have changed it to @JsonRootName("Wrapper").As per your json @jsonRootName should be set  to 'response' as response is your json's top level key.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check?